Is a 3-1/2" x 3-1/2" 1.8E parallam PSL header sufficient for 3' door opening in load-bearing wall?
I need to replace a header in a 3' rough opening.  This is in a load-bearing wall that runs down the middle of the house.  There is one floor above the wall.  House is 28' wide.  Is a 3.5" x 3.5" 1.8E parallam PSL sufficient?
This Weyerhaeuser tech note appears to indicate that this is sufficient but I don't understand what the difference is between the white and green rows.  Minimum and recommended?  The relevant table is the 2nd to last one, "FLOOR ONE STORY – 100% (SIMPLE SPAN ONLY)."  What was in there before is a pair of 2x4s laid flat on top of each other so I'm guessing the 4x4 is stronger.
I am certain that the wall is load-bearing.  The ends of all the 2nd floor joists rest on it.  The house is old and under-built by today's standards but all the lumber is old-growth douglas fir.

Are you sure it's load-bearing? Two flat 2x4s is a classic non-bearing header.

@isherwood Reasonably certain.  All the joist of the second floor rest on this wall.  The house is 70 years old.  It's under-built by today's standards but it's made of old-growth douglas fir.

We have very good precedent for asking about that, among other recurring themes, on this site.

No. The bare minimum bearing header is a double 2x6 (the 5¼" size for this product). That's even questionable for this span. I'd want to see a double 2x8 or 2x10. It doesn't matter that you have laminated lumber.

so is this article just wrong or is that because it's an outside wall?  The 2x8 or 2x10 seems extreme.

It may well meet nominal requirements, but in practice you'll never see 2x4 in an exterior wall. This has been true since the 80s, at least.

I think the use of 2x6s in exterior walls was more for extra insulation than strength.

We're talking about headers, with structural members in an upright orientation. Wall thickness isn't a factor. Load-bearing 2x4 walls had at least double 2x6 headers as far back as my experience goes.

@isherwood Can you tell what the difference is between the white and green rows in the tables in Weyerhaeuser's TB-611?

I can't. I can only speak from experience in the field .
